# useState updates state on second click

Tags: reactjs, state, use-effect, use-state

I've seen that this issue has been asked many times before but none of the answers make sense to me. After trying about every solution i could find, decided i'd just ask it myself.

Below is my code, the main issue being that in the DOM `filteredData` only changes on second click. Note, `projs` is the prop containing data fetched that gets filtered out and displayed

```
  const langs = ["react", "next js", "material-ui", "tailwind css", "firebase"];

  const [projectData, setProjectData] = useState([]);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setProjectData(projs);
  }, []);

  const handleCategory = (res) => {
    setCategory(res.data);
    const filter = projectData.filter((data) => data.category === category);
    setFilteredData(filter);
  };
```

button:

```
          {langs.map((data, index) => (
            <button
              key={index}
              class="px-2 sm:px-6 py-2 ring-2 font-semibold ring-portfBtnLight rounded-md transform hover:scale-110 transition duration-500"
              onClick={() => handleCategory({ data })}
            >
              {data}
            </button>
          ))}
```

I'm pretty lost at the moment, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the newly set value of a state in the same render cycle. To continue calling both `setState` calls in the same handler you need to use the category from `res.data` to generate the new filtered array and then set both.

```
const handleCategory = (res) => {
  const filter = projectData.filter((data) => data.category === res.data);
  setCategory(res.data);
  setFilteredData(filter);
};
```

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App({ projs }) {
  const langs = ["react", "next js", "material-ui", "tailwind css", "firebase"];

  const [projectData, setProjectData] = useState([]);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setProjectData(projs);
  }, [projs]); // need to watch for change as props won't update this automatically. Setting state from props is somewhat of an anti-pattern

  const handleCategory = (res) => {
    const filter = projectData.filter((data) => data.category === res.data);
    setCategory(res.data);
    setFilteredData(filter);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {langs.map((data) => (
        <button
          key={data} // avoid using index as key as this will lead to erros in updating.
          class={(data === category ? 'selected ' : '') + "px-2 sm:px-6 py-2 ring-2 font-semibold ring-portfBtnLight rounded-md transform hover:scale-110 transition duration-500"}
          onClick={() => handleCategory({ data })}
        >
          {data}
        </button>
      ))}
      <div>
        <h3>{category}</h3>
        {filteredData.length
          ? filteredData.map(p => (
            <div>
              <p>{p.value} – {p.category}</p>
            </div>
          ))
          : <p>No projects match</p>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const projectData = [{ id: 1, value: 'Project 1', category: 'react' }, { id: 2, value: 'Project 2', category: 'next js' }, { id: 3, value: 'Project 3', category: 'react' }, { id: 4, value: 'Project 4', category: 'material-ui' }]

ReactDOM.render(
  <App projs={projectData} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

Alternatively, update `filteredData` in a `useEffect` that watches for changes to either `category` or `projectData`

```
useEffect(() => {
  setFilteredData(projectData.filter((data) => data.category === category));
}, [category, projectData]);

const handleCategory = (res) => {
  setCategory(res.data);
};
```

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App({ projs }) {
  const langs = ["react", "next js", "material-ui", "tailwind css", "firebase"];

  const [projectData, setProjectData] = useState([]);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setProjectData(projs);
  }, [projs]); // need to watch for change as props won't update this automatically. Setting state from props is somewhat of an anti-pattern

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredData(projectData.filter((data) => data.category === category));
  }, [category, projectData]);

  const handleCategory = (res) => {
    setCategory(res.data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {langs.map((data) => (
        <button
          key={data}
          class={(data === category ? 'selected ' : '') + "px-2 sm:px-6 py-2 ring-2 font-semibold ring-portfBtnLight rounded-md transform hover:scale-110 transition duration-500"}
          onClick={() => handleCategory({ data })}
        >
          {data}
        </button>
      ))}
      <div>
        <h3>{category}</h3>
        {filteredData.length
          ? filteredData.map(p => (
            <div>
              <p>{p.value} – {p.category}</p>
            </div>
          ))
          : <p>No projects match</p>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const projectData = [{ id: 1, value: 'Project 1', category: 'react' }, { id: 2, value: 'Project 2', category: 'next js' }, { id: 3, value: 'Project 3', category: 'react' }, { id: 4, value: 'Project 4', category: 'material-ui' }]

ReactDOM.render(
  <App projs={projectData} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

As noted in the snippets –

Setting state from props is a bit of anti-pattern, but if you must you should add the prop to the dependency array so that state will be updated should the prop change. (prop changes don't force remounting).

Also, avoid using `index` as key, **especially** when mapping arrays whose order/membership will change as React will not update as expected.

Comment: this was it, thanks! makes sense, thanks for the tip with the `index` / key too

Comment: @starbvuks - which solution worked?  Because the first solution suggested seems the same as mine.  Or was it the suggestion to use `useEffect` or the key/index thing that sovled?

Comment: the `useEffect` suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the issue

```
setCategory(res.data);
const filter = projectData.filter((data) => data.category === category);
```

You invoke `setCategory`.  But that won't change the immediate value of `category` that you reference in the subsequent line.

I think you want this:

```
const updatedCategory = res.data;
setCategory(updatedCategory);
const filter = projectData.filter((data) => data.category === updatedCategory);
```

Also, is `res.data` actually the "category" thing you want to use?  I'm just asking because you use `data` between so many variables, parameters, and object members, I can't help but to wonder if it's really a typo.

Comment: yes `res.data` definitely is the category cause it works perfectly, but on the second click. Tried your alternative, the issue still persists.

Comment: And "category" is a number or string, correct?  If it's any other type (array or object), it's a different discussion.